Run Python script to Extract file in different folder
I have trouble with my Python script.
Currently, my script works to run the script which is file and myscript.py in the same folder.
I want to run myscript.py to extract files in another folder.
topology

myscript.py
import os
import re

# Setup main paths.
myfiles = os.listdir()

pattern = re.compile(r"filesextract\d+")

for files in myfiles:
    if(pattern.match(files) != None):
        command = "tar -xzvf " + files
        os.system(command)


I have two suggestions for you: 1. Read the TAR manual which answers your question with the explanation of the -C option. Read also the section about when and how to use the verbose option -v or --verbose or v in a combined options list which is nearly never needed on extraction. 2. Read the Python documentations about the more than 10 years deprecated os.system and the now to use subprocess module.

make the script accept input and output directory (extraction) as arguments (or envs), or find a better approach to set these depending on your scenario, so that you can run the script from any location.
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Usage: python myscript.py <input_directory> <output_directory>")
    sys.exit(1)

# Get the input and output directories from the arguments
input_directory = sys.argv[1]
output_directory = sys.argv[2]


example: tar -xf a.tar.gz -C /opt
man tar
see: To move file hierarchies, invoke tar as
tar -cf - -C srcdir . | tar -xpf - -C destdir

You'll need to make changes to your script so that it references the folder where the file extraction script is located in order to execute it. By providing the folder path as a parameter, you may use os.listdir() to list the files in the particular folder.
